# Need help with Hilbert-style proof (Given ¬q and (¬p⇒(¬q⇒¬r)), prove (r⇒p))

Tags: logic, proof-writing, hilbert-calculus

Given $\neg q$ and $(\neg p⇒(¬q⇒¬r))$, prove $(r⇒p)$. I unfortunately can't figure out how to begin this proof. Do any of you have any idea how to begin this proof? I'd appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser Read the second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\neg p \to (\neg q \to \neg r)$ is logically equivalent to $( \neg p \land q) \lor (r \to p)$. The result is trivial now given $\neg q$.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you are supposed to do this. What I would do is:

1. Use Permutation to get ${\neg} q \Rightarrow ({\neg}p \Rightarrow {\neg}r)$
2. Detach to get ${\neg}p \Rightarrow {\neg}r$
3. Use Contraposition to get $r \Rightarrow p$